# Is my solution correct for solving $\cos(z)=2$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification

Find all roots in $\mathbb{C}$ of the equation $\cos(z)=2$ and plot them on an Argand diagram.

My solution: $\cos(z)=2$, $z=x+iy$ so we have that $\cos(x)\cos(iy)-\sin(x)\sin(iy)=2$ so $\cos(x)\cosh(y)=2$ and $\sin(x)\sinh(y)=0$ must hold. So if $\sinh(y)=0$ then $y=0$ so $\cosh(y)=1$ and so $\cos(x)=2$ which is a contradiction, therefore $x=n\pi$, for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and so $\cos(x)=\pm 1$. However, $\cosh(y)>0$, so if $\cos(x)=-1$ it follows that $\cos(x)\cosh(y)<0$ and cannot equal $2$. Hence $\cos(x)=1$ so $x=2n\pi$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y=\pm\cosh^{-1}(2)$ since $\cosh(y)=2$. Therefore since $z=x+iy$ $\implies z=2n\pi \pm i\cosh^{-1}(2)$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

My question is, is this sufficent to answer the question $\cos(z)=2$? And if not how should I structure it using this method? Also why is it $\pm\cosh^{-1}(2)$? I don't understand this sutble point. And if I was to draw an Argand diagram would it just be on the imaginary axis at $\cosh^{-1}(2)$ every $2n\pi$?

Comment: It's likely $\pm$ because $\cos(z) = \cos(-z)$, so both will be "the same" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is good. About $\pm\cosh^{-1}(2)$, the fact is that $\cosh(-y)=\cosh(y)$, but $\cosh^{-1}(2)$ only returns the positive number $y$ such that $\cosh(y)=2$ and also its negative is an admissible solution of the problem.

However, there's a simpler solution. Recall that
$$
\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=\frac{w^2+1}{2w}
$$
where $w=e^{iz}$. Then the equation is
$$
w^2-4w+1=0
$$
or $w=2\pm\sqrt{3}$. If $z=x+iy$, then $w=e^{iz}=e^{-y}e^{ix}$. Then
$$
e^{-y}e^{ix}=(2+\sqrt{3})e^{i0}
$$
gives $y=-\log(2+\sqrt{3})=\log(2-\sqrt{3})$ and $ix=2n\pi i$, so
$$
z=2n\pi+i\log(2-\sqrt{3})
$$
and, similarly, for $2-\sqrt{3}$ we get
$$
z=2n\pi+i\log(2+\sqrt{3})
$$

Comment: why is it an admissible solution? and am i correct about how i would plot it on an argand diagram?

Comment: @Gibberish As I said, there are two real numbers $y$ such that $\cosh(y)=2$, but $\cosh^{-1}(2)$ only returns the positive one. There is no periodicity involved.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense now thank you!. &so there is only one point at $Z$ but how do i find the argument of $z$ if it has those components to plot it?

Comment: @Gibberish You get points with imaginary part $\log(2+\sqrt{3})$ or $\log(2-\sqrt{3})$ and real part $2n\pi$. Just plot them.

Comment: I dont understand the real part, since $n\in \Bbb Z$ so where would that go on the real axis?

Comment: would there be two solutions every 2npi?

Comment: @Gibberish Yes, that's it